# Maven-Publish does not publish API/Implementation dependencies in POM

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I am using `maven-publish` plugin in gradle to publish artifacts. I need to generate a POM file that contains dependencies so that my consumers can fetch the needed dependencies.

Since `maven-publish` does not by default contains dependencies onto POM file, I had to use

```
pom.withXml {
            def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
            configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('scope', 'compile')
            }
        }
```

It was all working fine to me until I swapped keyword `compile` to `api` or `Implementation`. 
the published POM does not contain any dependencies uses keyword `api` or `Implementation`. I had to use `compile` to make it included in POM file, am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3):

After couple of hours searching online, I just realized that the property you include POM file is changed as well.

It now become

```
//for implementation dependencies
configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each { ... }

//for api dependencies
configurations.api.allDependencies.each { ... }
```

However,

```
configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each { ... }
```

seems includes `api` dependencies in the POM file already.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply skip the scope part, you hardly come across maven dependencies with scopes. ':D